# Need a pom.xml format for c++ project build in visual studio

Tags: maven, msbuild, pom.xml

I would like to build a C++ project using maven and MSBuild. can someone help me?

Comment: So what have you found so far on the internet, what have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: I didnt get a proper guidance from internet.  tried creating a pom file as shown in different sites. Most of the examples for java or c++ compilation using cmake file. Could you help me to figure out the best method. IS two pom.xml madatory in maven. I am very much new to maven.